# Load more from database not working when changing content type to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to stop my 'load more' button from displaying once there is no more results to show.

So, my plan was that once the load more button was clicked and the query ran on the database, i would do a rowcount and then if that number was less than what was requested in the LIMIT claus then i would return that information.

So currently my js script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=follow&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop();
              pageIndex++;
              $("#buildcontainer").masonry()
           }

        });

    });

});
});
```

This works fine, but i wanted to put a JSON return in my loadmorebuilds.php page.

So the plan was to do e.g.

```
// check if the results count is less than requested
if ($checkforlast < 8) {
    $return['noMore'] = true;
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

I would then change my js to look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=follow&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
              pageIndex++;
              $("#buildcontainer").masonry()

              if (response.correctKey === true) {
                DO SOMETHING TO REMOVE BUTTON
              }

           }

        });

    });

});
});
```

The problem comes when i change the content type:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Because thats changing how the data i send back is (i think?). Changing the content type results in no new content being shown and nothing happens on the load more button being clicked.

is there another way to send the databack to the ajax call if there is less results than requested and without changing the content type?

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: making a content-type decision at run-time seems like an overcomplicated way to go. Why not just return the string 'noMore' and test for that value in the success callback before you append?

Comment: Because then you're trading off content-type declaration for string parsing and replacement -- they'd have to strip "noMore" from the HTML before displaying it. Returning data is the right way to go here.

Comment: Why not try adding dataType: "json", to ajax request?

Comment: @Neil thanks for the reply, maybe its because its late, but any chance you can expand on how i would go about that? as in what do i send in the php page and then how do i check it in the success call back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @palpatim that string parsing is probably not the best way to go here. But this solution could work as well, and wouldnt require you building your html from json on the client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pageIndex = 1;
  $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=follow&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
        success: function(html) {
          var el = jQuery(html),
              rowCount = el.find('tr').length;

          jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
          $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
          pageIndex++;
          $("#buildcontainer").masonry();

          if (rowCount < 8) {
            DO SOMETHING TO REMOVE BUTTON
          }
       }
    });
});
});
```

I used 'tr' here to denote the element you're using to hold each result in markup.

Comment: sorry to keep not fully understanding! this is a big learning process. the $el.find what that do? does that find the value of the element specified?

So i have tried in the loadmore.php to put e.g. <div id="countvar">ECHO THE COUNT</div> This does show the count everytime more results are loaded. 

However i tried this: rowCount = $el.find('#countvar').length;

But nothing happens, if i put that line where you placed it in the code it also seems to break it and doesnt load any more results.

Comment: Could you post the actual markup you are sending down as the response?

Comment: removed the el.find and just done $('rowcount').length and it works. Much thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning JSON, then you can't expect to simply append the JSON to the DOM as you were previously doing. Consider your success handler:

```
success: function(html) {
  var el = jQuery(html);
  jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
  $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
  pageIndex++;
  $("#buildcontainer").masonry()

  if (response.correctKey === true) {
    DO SOMETHING TO REMOVE BUTTON
  }

}
```

Change the success handler's argument from `html` to `json` or even better `data, textStatus, jqXHR`. Also consider using jQuery's `getJSON()` method as a shorthand. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Then you can use the `data` to populate your presentation as appropriate, and inspect the `noMore` attribute using `data.noMore`.

Comment: But this solution moves the template layer to the client, which isn't necessarily a trivial exercise.